# Homemade bicycle remedies

Tags: cleaning, lubricant, rust

essential shops are closed, has anyone got any household remedies for any problems with your bike? ie: lubrication, rust removal degreasers well any homemade or household stuff uses for your bike.

Comment: While is it a good question, it very open ended question that has no succinct answer, so it does not fit the SE format very well.  You are welcome to ask multiple questions that are more specific, such as 'What cleaners from around home will work on my chain"  (many of them have already been asked on this site)

Comment: However in the UK at least, bike shops are classed as essential and remain open, as they did in lockdown 1

Comment: Yeah I was wondering why our motorworld store is open yet the local pawns hops or cash convertor type shops are shut,As I think with the current economic climate and ppl short on cash as always Rules&regulations are not thought out properly like as b4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice one is the use of with-vinegar for rust removal. Works quite nicely on bolts and rusted bits.
Not personally tried, but some people reccomend the use of furnitre polish to wax your bike, to create a sort of a coat able to protect from water and moisture.
WD40 to simply remove old stickers and "unknown" dirt on the bike frame.

Comment: I've got a rusty chain on my voodoo mountain bike might give it a try  thx

Comment: It works ok for rusty chain as well, but don't overdo because I destroyed an old chain by trying to de-rust like this. Most of the time 12-24h are enough to weak the rust and makes it remove easier.

Comment: It was given to me after being left outdoors so I've already got it unstuck by handling &moving each link ((well I've ad the time being on lock down lol)) and also used dettolwipes wrapped around chain and by turning the pedals slowly around

Comment: most of the people suggest to replace the chain, but most of the time you can safely use an old one, if it's rusted probably it has not been used so much so it should not be stretched. And if you want to reuse and old chain probably you don't want to ride the bike too much, so no real worries here.

Answer (score 0):

Ithink cola is a great cleaning/stain remover...

Answer (score 0):

Dish detergent, general cleaning products all work on bikes. Dish detergent does not work as well as a dedicated de-greaser for getting dirt off chains and sprockets but it does a decent job. Chains can also wiped down with a rag and WD-40.

Chain lube is where you really need a proper bike product, but that is what ordering online is for.

Check out this GCN video where WD-40 used used as a chain degreaser

Comment: " *chain lube is where you really need a proper bike product* " Unless you intend to use dry lube, i doubt. AFAIK a GCN video (not sure which one exactly) cited a study or such which indicated that virgin olive oil outperformed bike-specific wet lubes in terms of efficiency. Normal cooking oils should thereby be just alright , as wet lubes, shouldn't they ? I'm genuinely curious and would love to hear you reasoning behind your assertion.